# Is there any way that i can retrieve account_id from google contact api v3 to make a get request to google people api?

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I have retrieved all my contacts using Google Contact API. Now, i want to get the google profile info of all those contacts using the get request as mentioned in this [People API GET](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) link. But i do not see any id in the response to make a request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Contacts API and People API are separate API's not meant to interop with each other.

That said, the reverse engineered way to do this is to take the Contacts API contact ID, parse that hexadecimal value, convert it to decimal, and add a 'c' prefix to it, and that becomes the People API person resource ID.

e.g. if the Contacts API contact ID  was `100`, then the People API person ID would be `c256`. When you fetch contacts from the People API in this fashion, it'll have the joined profile information, if present.

Comment: Wow! it's working like a charm. Don't know why such information is not included in the documentation of the API. Thanks.

Comment: Be sure to mark this as an answer (along with any previous questions you've asked that were successfully answered). I notice that none of your previous questions have been marked as answered.

Comment: Sure, i will do that.