# Is there any way to get Google People API resource ID from Google Contacts contact Id?

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-people-api

We store the user's contactId in our database and use it to fetch/edit/delete contacts when the user requests from our app. Now that Google Contacts API is to be sunset, we need to call Google People API for these actions using resource id.

**Is there any way to get Google People API resource ID from Google Contacts contact Id?**

I found the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349746/is-there-any-way-that-i-can-retrieve-account-id-from-google-contact-api-v3-to-ma/46355535#46355535) in Stackoverflow:

> The Contacts API and People API are separate API's not meant to
> interop with each other.
>
> That said, the reverse engineered way to do this is to take the
> Contacts API contact ID, parse that hexadecimal value, convert it to
> decimal, and add a 'c' prefix to it, and that becomes the People API
> person resource ID.
>
> e.g. if the Contacts API contact ID was 100, then the People API
> person ID would be c256. When you fetch contacts from the People API
> in this fashion, it'll have the joined profile information, if
> present.

I tried the solution and it is working, but need to know whether we can use this conversion error free (i.e without any exceptions) to populate the respective resource id to the contact id.

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer:

While the workaround provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46355535) seems to work, I think there's a more  documented way to find the People API's `resourceName` based on the `contactId`.

This `contactId` is part of the [Person resource](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people), as long as the connection is coming from `CONTACTS`.

More specifically, this information can be found as part of the resource at:

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/c...",
  "metadata": {
    "sources": [
      {
        "type": "CONTACT",
        "id": "CONTACT_ID" // Converting to decimal and adding "people/c" results in resource name
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Therefore, if you have an array of valid `contactId`, you could find the corresponding `resourceNames` by listing your connections (see [people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list)) and checking whether the `contactId` matches the `id` in the nested field and retrieving the `resourceName` for that connection if that's the case.

#### Code sample:

For example, using Apps Script, you could retrieve a mapping of `contactId` and `resourceName`, like this:

```
function getResourceNamesFromContactIds(contactIds) { // contactIds: array with valid contactIds
  const resourceName = "people/me";
  const optionalArgs = {
    personFields: "metadata",
    sources: "READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT"
  }
  const connections = People.People.Connections.list(resourceName, optionalArgs)["connections"];
  const mapping = contactIds.map(contactId => {
    const foundConnection = connections.find(connection => {
      return contactId == connection["metadata"]["sources"][0]["id"];
    });
    if (foundConnection) {
      return {
        contactId: contactId,
        resourceName: foundConnection["resourceName"]
      }
    }
  }).filter(el => el);
  return mapping;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We did see the that sources param of the People API contained contactId. 
But in our case, we will be calling the edit/delete APIs with a scheduler sync. So we are looking for a way to get the "contact Id - Resource Id" mapping before we move the our users to People API. Also getting the resource id without calling any API will be best for us as,
1. Every user may have upto 25k contacts. And the max limit of people.connections.list is 1000. So that's 25 calls for 1 user.
2. We have around 15k users, so the API calls will raise exponentially.

Comment: So if "Converting to decimal and adding "people/c" results in resource name" works, can we proceed with that?

Comment: @Ranjani If you don't want to use People API, I think converting to decimal will be your best option. It's not documented but it seems to work.

Comment: If I use this conversion for the "contact Id - Resource Id" mapping, will it return the correct resource Id for all the contact Ids? Or will there be any breakage for any set of users?

Comment: @Ranjani Well, the hexadecimal-decimal conversion seems to work, but since it's not documented it could change without notice. I think the conversion I suggested is safer, since it's based on the documented person resource of People API. Of course, you can always check whether the retrieved resource name is valid after making the decimal conversion, but that would require using the API anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doesn't work for contacts that don't have email addresses.

There's no need to get the metadata object from `person.emailAddresses`, we can get it directly from the person object which doesn't require any other field to be present in the person's info.

Also, the accepted answer assumes the first source is always of type "CONTACT" which may not be the case, in which case you might get the wrong contact-id

Here's the improved version (in Java):

```
List<Person> people = getPeople();// fetch all pages of the user contacts, with "personFields" set to "metadata" only.

Map<String, String> mapping = new HashMap<>();

people.forEach(person -> {
    PersonMetadata metadata = person.getMetadata();
    if (metadata != null) {
        List<Source> sources = metadata.getSources();
        if (sources != null) {
            sources.stream()
                .filter(srcObj -> "CONTACT".equalsIgnoreCase(srcObj.getType()))
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(source ->
                    mapping.put(source.getId(), person.getResourceName()));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice `metadata` is a valid `personField`, thank you for that. Also, `sources` can be used when making the request, no need to filter it after receiving the response. Finally, please note that the Apps Script example I provided is just that, an example. The user didn't ask for a specific code, just if there's a way to retrieve this information.

Comment: Also, the hexadecimal to decimal conversion works even for contacts that don't have email addresses. I enquired that to Google and was told I could use the hack for a one-time migration provided I do the conversion within the next month. After that, they cannot say if it will remain unchanged.