# Google People API: Any relation between Metadata and resourceName on a Person object

Tags: google-api, metadata, google-people-api

When use new Google People API to get a `Person` object, is there a relation between `Person.Metadata.Sources[0].id` and `Person.ResouceName`? like the `resouceName` is calculated from the `Person.Metadata.Sources[0].id`

The reason why I asked this is in the old Google Contacts API, we store the contact URL like `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/[email]/full/3c8fcc428ca19658` which I noticed the suffix string `3c8fcc428ca19658` is the same as the `Person.Metadata.Sources[0].id` in new Google People API, so we can easily know the old URL match which resouceName?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean this to use the [Method: people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) method? If that is the case it is stated that you need to use the resourceName as `people/{account_id}`

Comment: Above image shows the person object get from [Method: people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get), what I am asking is any relation between the values `Person.Metadata.Sources[0].id` and `Person.ResouceName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can calculate a `resourceName` from a contact-ID but it's not documented and cannot be trusted to work, however a Google engineer privately guaranteed this should work in the next month.

See original answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46355535/819355
and discussion in comments here: [Is there any way to get Google People API resource ID from Google Contacts contact Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67380143/is-there-any-way-to-get-google-people-api-resource-id-from-google-contacts-conta/67482082#67482082)