# Google People API: Get contact by a specific group

Tags: api, google-people-api

I am migrating our code from Google Contacts API to Google People API as Google Contacts API will be deprecated soon, but I noticed new People APIs are simple to compare with the old Contacts API.

How I can find a contact for a specific group?
f.e. `getContactByGroupId`

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

Assuming that you meant [getContactGroupById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getcontactgroupbyidid) instead of `getContactByGroupId`, you can retrieve a specific contact group in People API by calling:

- [contactGroups.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/get)

#### Further info:

In this case, you have to provide the `resourceName` instead of the contact id. If you don't know how to get the former, consider taking a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46355535).

If you are using Apps Script, you can enable the [Advanced People Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/people) and do something like this:

```
People.ContactGroups.get(resourceName);
```

Comment: No, I'd like to get a Contact according to some Group via PeopleAPI

Comment: @StepanRyzhevich Could you clarify what Contacts API method would this correspond to?